# How do I open the gate in the Familiar Forest?

Tags: chantelise-a-tale-of-two-sisters

In the Familiar Forest in Chantelise, there is a wandering traveller selling equipment and a gate, like the ones that would normally be unlocked in a stage by killing all the enemies. However, there are no enemies or hidden switches to be seen. Is this gate opened at a certain point in the plot or is there a hidden way for me to open it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Familiar Forest is a late-game area that can only be accessed when you have **acquired every secret treasure on all of the other maps**. Once you have done so, then you will be allowed access to the later sections of the Familiar Forest. So, if you haven't been feverishly ensuring that you've collecting all of the secret treasures, it's best to start now if you want to access this place. ♪

Comment: Ah...this is what I was most afraid of.

Comment: Actually, I have a question about this; in order to consider a secret treasure acquired, can I simply open the treasure chest and then go back to the world map?

Comment: @Mana As long as the stage is considered "Treasure clear", so you can even die in the stage and it'll be fine.